# Access objects across AD domains with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

I'm using the ldap3 module with Python and need to be able to find all members, recursively, of objects within multiple AD domains.

We have domains like:

- DOMAIN.COM
- UK.DOMAIN.COM
- US.DOMAIN.COM

The groups I need to get members from are in DOMAIN.COM but the users and groups inside these groups can be from any of the domains. I can see group members that are users/groups in the DOMAIN.COM and I can also list users from any domain that are in a group that is in DOMAIN.COM but my problem is that we will have groups/users from UK.DOMAIN.COM etc that are members of one of the groups in DOMAIN.COM and I can't seem to get it working.

I'm using the following:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL_ATTRIBUTES, SUBTREE
import getpass

USERNAME = 'DOMAIN\User'
PASSWORD=getpass.getpass('Enter Password: ') # For testing only
GROUPS = [
    'CN=MyGroup,OU=Security Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM',
]

server = Server('DOMAIN.COM', use_ssl=True)
with Connection(server,
        read_only=True,
        check_names=True,
        lazy=False,
        raise_exceptions=True,
        user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD) as c:

    for group in GROUPS:
        c.search(
            search_base='dc=DOMAIN,dc=COM',
            search_filter='(&(memberOf=%s)(objectCategory=*))' % group,
            search_scope=SUBTREE,
            attributes=ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
            get_operational_attributes=True)

        print(c.response[0])
```